# get particular image with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am currently implementing a system where I require to make a image layer on hover of a particular image. From jquery how is it possible to get and set visibility of a particular image only even if they have the same class.

This is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imgclass').mouseover(function() {
        $('.hoverimg').css('visibility','visible');
        $('.hoverimg').css('opacity','0.6');
    });
    $('.imgclass').mouseout(function() {
        $('.hoverimg').css('visibility','hidden');
    });
});
```

To make it more clear this is an example I made. http://jsfiddle.net/xwj4A/

As you can see atm when one hovers on a particular image both images visibility is set to visible (as they have the same class). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right , you need `this` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imgclass').mouseover(function() {
        $('.hoverimg' ,this).css('visibility','visible');
        $('.hoverimg' ,this).css('opacity','0.6');
    });
    $('.imgclass').mouseout(function() {
        $('.hoverimg' ,this).css('visibility','hidden');
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xwj4A/8/

Comment: Hey , silent down-voter , i've found my mistake and edited my answer!!

Comment: @comb great! seems to me mine is little bit better for performance because of `this` is used as is , without turning it into jQuery object (`$(this)`)..

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$('.hoverimg')
```

with:

```
$(this).find('.hoverimg')
```

In order to only select the `.hoverimg` elements that exists within the hovered container.

Answer (score -1):

You have to apply new styles to target element instead of all elements with same class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imgclass').mouseover(function() {
        $('.hoverimg', this).css({
            visibility: 'visible', 
            opacity: 0.6
        });
    });
    $('.imgclass').mouseout(function() {
        $('.hoverimg', this).css('visibility','hidden');
    });
});
```

$(this) refers to actual element which triggered event.